Protobuf compatibility for Events
I'm looking at protobuf for events, and struggling to reconcile with my understanding of schema compatibility/evolution.
With Avro and Json, compatibility rules are applied as follows:

API requests/Command Messages - backward compatibility (Delete fields, Add optional fields)
API responses/Event Messages - forward compatibility (Add fields, Delete optional fields)

If an event is breaking forward compatibility, create a new schema for v2, and publish both v1 and v2 in different topics until all consumers switch to v2
proto3 removed required fields so that such concerns handled at application layer (instead of transport). There's tools like buf to help with that..
Buf has this weird concept of file vs wire, distinguishing compatibility according to whether it breaks code generation or the wire. I don't see how breaking codegen matters. Compatibility is about making sure consumers expecting v1.1 can still consume v1.2. If they need to refactor a little when updating to 1.2 it's not a big deal.
Even if validation moved from proto to buf, consumers/clients will still fail.
Here's some scenarios:

Removing a field from an event that is defined required with buf, and consumer expects/needs that field. I am not sure how reserving the number will help in not breaking consumers. (to be fair this is not allowed with FILE compatibility)

Removing a field should be allowed for commands and requests.

Adding a field in requests or Command that is defined required with buf. Clients requests will now start to fail because this change is considered as non-breaking.


The ideal is that CI pipelines prevent making breaking contract changes according to how the schema will be used. Having 1 set of rules for everything, just means that some breaking changes are not detected and need to be considered on a case by case basis by the developer to prevent breaking consumers, or that non-breaking changes are rejected unnecessarily.
What am I missing?
